# Which event capture mail sending information in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email-translation, send-mail

My requirement is capture email subject, from address . and email body content , for all kind of mail sending Which  event capture mail sending information in magento 2

Answer (score 3):

You need to overwrite the `Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport` class.

Create file `app/code/Foo/EmailLogger/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<!-- Overwriting Mail Send Transport-->
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport" type="Foo\EmailLogger\Framework\Mail\Transport"/>
```

Create file `app/code/Foo/EmailLogger/Framework/Mail/Transport.php`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\EmailLogger\Framework\Mail;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport as CoreTransport;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Foo\EmailLogger\Model\EmailLogger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Foo\EmailLogger\Helper\Data as EmaiLoggerHelper;

class Transport extends CoreTransport
{
   /**
    * @var LoggerInterface
    */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var EmailLogger
     */
     protected $emailLogger;

     /**
      * @var EmaiLoggerHelper
      */
     protected $helper;

     /**
      * @param LoggerInterface $logger
      * @param EmailLogger $emailLogger
      * @param EmaiLoggerHelper $helper
      * @param MessageInterface $message
      * @param array $parameters
      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
      */
      public function __construct(
         LoggerInterface $logger,
         EmailLogger $emailLogger,
         MessageInterface $message,
         $parameters = null
      ) {
         $this->logger      = $logger;
         $this->emailLogger = $emailLogger;
         parent::__construct($message, $parameters);
      }


      /**
       * Send a mail using this transport
       *
       * @return void
       * @throws \Exception
       */
       public function sendMessage()
       {
           try {
               /** @var \Zend_Mime_Part $body **/
               $body = $this->_message->getBody();
               $this->emailLogger->log(
                   $this->_message->getRecipients(),
                   $this->_message->getFrom(),
                   $this->_message->getSubject(),
                   $this->_message->getHeaders(),
                   $body->type,
                   $body->getRawContent()
               );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        parent::sendMessage();
    }
}//end class
```

Now depending on your requirement you can write your capture logic in `Foo\EmailLogger\Model\EmailLogger::log()`

Comment: When send mail event occur, while update getting email details to custom table in database, that's why i prefer for event observer method. suppose you know, how to update  this value to custom table  I will take this.

Comment: There is no event present when a mail is sent, so we cant use observer.

Comment: @AtishGoswami, is there any way to get template code  and template body ?